# How to scan and return Wifi channels in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wifi

I am currently working on an app that searches for available wifi networks and returns the signal, quality and MAC address using .net core 2.
I just want to know if there is any built-in class or api for this purpose or not.

Comment: Not sure if will run on net core.  Here is a window dll you can call : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.wlanqueryinterface

Comment: No, there is no build-in class/api. You have to use Native WiFi for that or third party libraries. Native WiFi returns frequency that can be then translated to channel in your application.